# Yii2 Sum of a Column Based on Filter Option

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a `GridView` and 6 filter options placed on radio buttons. When I click a filter, the `GridView` will change based on the filter being clicked. Here's a picture:

[image]

Now, I want to get the total `Converted Amount` of the table based on the filter chosen. For example, if I choose `Draft` filter, the table will show all `Draft` reimbursements and will sum up its `Converted Amount` and total will be placed at the top right side above the table as shown in the photo.

I tried googling solutions for this one but I find no answer. Here's a snippet of my code in my controller:

```
$refreshData = false;

if (isset(Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'])) {
    $refreshData = true;
    $sortby = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'];
} else {
    $sortby = 'Show All';
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Reimbursement::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])])
    ]);
}

// get all reimbursements
$reimbursements = Reimbursement::findAll(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])]);

if (isset(Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'])) {
    if(Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'] != '' && Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'] != 'Show All') {
        $refreshData = true;
        $reimbursements = Reimbursement::findAll(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id']), 'status' => Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby']]);
        // $ids = [];
        // foreach ($reimbursements as $i => $model) {
        //     $ids[] = $model['_id'];
        // }

        // $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT sum(total) FROM estimate WHERE `_id` IN ('.implode(',',$ids).')'); // please use a prepared statement instead, just a proof of concept
        // $sum = $command->queryScalar();
    } elseif (Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'] == 'Show All') { 
        $refreshData = true;
    }
}

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $reimbursements,
]);

if($refreshData) {
    return $this->renderPartial('_index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 
    ]);
}

$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 10;
return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'rModel' => $rModel,
]);
```

As you may have noticed I commented some lines of code below `if(Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'] != '' && Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'] != 'Show All')` condition. I tried that one and it doesn't work.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
        $reimbursements = Reimbursement::find()->where(['company_id' => new \MongoId($session['company_id'])]);

    if (isset(Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'])) {
        $refreshData = true;
        $sortby = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby'];
        $reimbursements->andWhere(['status' => Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()['sortby']]);
    } else {
        $refreshData = false;
        $sortby = 'Show All';
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $reimbursements,
    ]);

    $totalSum = $reimbursements->sum('total');
```

Comment: it returns an error `Call to a member function sum() on a non-object`

Comment: $reimbursements is a yii\db\Query object. You can use this object as query parameter in  ActiveDataProvider, select all rows by this query ( $reimbursements->all() as select * from ...) or select sum of column ($reimbursements->sum('column') as select sum(column) from ... )